# How does "sort -t . -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n" work?

Tags: shell, unix

I've come across this command which sorts the hosts file by ip, but I just can't break down the syntax so it would make sense. All I understood was that the first part means that the dot is used as delimeter, and then I got lost in all the commas and the rest of the arguments:

```
$ sort -t . -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
192.168.100.101 site1.com dev-db
192.168.100.102 site2.com prod-db
192.168.101.20  site3.com dev-web
192.168.101.21  site4.com prod-web
```

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't `sort -V` achieve the same thing?

Comment: It would be helpful to explain *how* you're "lost in all the commas" -- that is, when you read the relevant parts of `man sort`, how do you interpret them? Which specific language from that documentation is it (quoted in the question, ideally) where the meaning is unclear? Note that there's a strong lean towards closing "explain this code" questions as "too broad", unless they're very explicitly narrowed; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334553/where-should-we-ask-for-code-explanations

Comment: I asked a legitimate question, am I supposed to apologize?

Comment: Perhap you get confused comparing the syntax with commas in normal sentences. When you think that parts between commas belong together, it is really confusing. Don't look at `2n -k 3` but look at `-k 2,2n`.

Comment: It sounds like you first need to understand how the shell parses that into a sequence of words. The commas are, to some extent, irrelevant on the first pass. The shell splits on whitespace, yielding `sort`, `-t`, `.`, `-k`, `1,1n`, `-k`, `2,2n`, etc. After that, it becomes a question of how `sort` *interprets* the remaining words, which it receives as its arguments.

Answer (score 2):

`-k` designates a field-range. `1,1` (and the others respectively) express just one field, assuring that the sorting happens with precedence from left to right, and then within the already sorted subset. the `n` tacked on means "sort the column numerically".